# How do I use "stop" as a keyword to stop the for loop?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to set "numberOfItems" as a large number but want to stop the loop midway.  I need help for the while part. No ArrayList please, I'm not familiar with that yet.

```
do
 {
    for(int i=0; i<=numberOfItems; i++)
    {
       System.out.println("Enter product name");
       productName[i]=input.nextLine();
       System.out.println("Enter price of product");
       productPrice[i]=input.nextDouble();
       System.out.printf("%s,%n,%.2f",productName[i],productPrice[i]);
    }
 }
 while (! (productName[i]= input.nextLine("stop")));
```

Comment: Use `break` wherever you want to come out of the loop.

Comment: Do you need the break statement? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_break_statement.htm

Comment: You have two loops, which one do you want to stop?

Comment: @zangetsu ichinose you don't have enough experience in java otherwise you wouldn't have accepted an answer in which your program can be easily crashed by the user and escaped an answer that makes your program more convenient!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at how your code is working, the most sensible place to break is probably after entering a product name. This would mean you can't store a STOP product... I've left this as UPPERCASE (you can use [equalsIgnoreCase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-) if you don't care about case).

Something like this:

```java
    for(int i=0; i<=numberOfItems; i++)
    {
       System.out.println("Enter product name (or STOP to stop)");
       String tmpProduct = input.nextLine();

       //trim to avoid whitespace
       if ("STOP".equals(tmpProduct.trim())) {
          break; //we stop the loop here
       }

       //they didn't type STOP, guess they wanted a product.
       productName[i]=tmpProduct;


       System.out.println("Enter price of product");
       productPrice[i]=input.nextDouble();
       System.out.printf("%s,%n,%.2f",productName[i],productPrice[i]);
    }
```

This also avoids the need for the outer loop. If you would rather ask after every product (this could get annoying after a while) then you can put the check and prompt after requesting the double.

```java
    for(int i=0; i<=numberOfItems; i++)
    {
       System.out.println("Enter product name");

       //they didn't type STOP, guess they wanted a product.
       productName[i]=input.nextLine();

       System.out.println("Enter price of product");
       productPrice[i]=input.nextDouble();
       System.out.printf("%s,%n,%.2f",productName[i],productPrice[i]);

       System.out.println("type STOP to stop or anything else to continue");
       String tmp = input.nextLine();
       //trim to avoid whitespace problems
       if ("STOP".equals(tmp.trim())) {
          break; //we stop the loop here
       }
    }
```

Comment: That is why I provided both loops - please explain how the program can crash easily - the only way I can currently forsee that happening is on invalid input - catching the exception would prevent this but that was not what the asker asked for. If you are able to provide such an example I will happly amend my answer.

There are **exactly** two ways (not including abnormal termination) to terminate each loop, as documented in my answer.

Comment: by the way, nextDouble() doesn't read till the newLine char, so it will mess up everything after the first loop. next time please try to run your code before submitting!

Comment: I used the example code provided by @zangetsuichinose and modified it as they requested. Kept it as simple as possible to meet their requirements and tried to present it in an understandable way. If the submitter has any issues they can contact me and I'll be more than happy to fix my solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can put an `if` statement inside of your `for` loop to decide when to stop it; the instruction to stop a loop is `break`.

Note that this means you don't need the enclosing `do` loop.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** This is enhanced answer explained in details

```
// this method to validate the input after reading the entire line
static public Object interpretedInput(String line){
   if(line.replace(" ", "").equalsIgnoreCase("stop")){ // if stop detected 
      return null; 
   }
   else {// if it's not stop
       for(char c : line.toCharArray()){ // read every char in the line
           if(!Character.isDigit(c) && c!='.'){ // if any non digit is detected that means it should be considered as a string 
              //(note if you want the product name to consist of digits only -> this won't work)
              return line; // return line
          }
      }
   }
   try{return Double.valueOf(line);} // else try to parse the line to extract the double value and return it
   catch(NumberFormatException e){return null;}
}


Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int numberOfItems = 10; // for example
String[]productName = new String[10];
double[] productPrice = new double[10];
for(int i=0; i<numberOfItems; i++){
    System.out.println("Enter product name");
    Object theInput = interpretedInput(input.nextLine()); // the method will return either null or string or double 
    if(theInput==null){ // if it's null that means to stop
         break;
    }
    else if (theInput instanceof String){ // if it's instance of string accept it 
            productName[i]=(String)theInput;
    }
    while(!(theInput instanceof Double)){ // this will repeat until a valid double input is entered 
         //then it will assign it and display the content
         System.out.println("Enter price of product");
         theInput = interpretedInput(input.nextLine());
         if(theInput==null){
              i=numberOfItems; // to terminate the parent for loop as well
                break;
         }
         else if (theInput instanceof Double){
             productPrice[i]=(Double)theInput;
             System.out.printf("%s, %.2f\n",productName[i],productPrice[i]);
         }
         else{System.out.println("Invalid Price");}
    }
}
```